# How to create and insert record with unix timestamp - sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server, unix-timestamp

I want to create the following table:

```
user_id     unix_timestamp      platform     Action
   1         1501688421118         IOS         A
```

My create table is:

```
create table C (
user_id integer,
unix_timestamp timestamp,
platform varchar(50),
Action varchar(50)   
);
```

Then I want to insert row:

```
INSERT INTO C 
VALUES ('1', 1501688421118, 'IOS','A');
```

I got error, i tried varbinary(8) instead of timestamp but when i am doing the insert, i am binary result in unix_timestamp column instead of 1501688421118.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? SQL, the language has well defined date-related types. All database products support them one way or another and SQL Server many date-related types. Date values can be indexed and searched. That unix "timestamp" though is nothing more than a 64-bit integer until someone parses it in some way.

Comment: if you somehow care about space, [datetime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with precision less than 3 (milliseconds) uses only 6 bytes. Date optimizations mean that you can write `Where cast(entrydate as date)='2019-01-10'` and get a range query that returns any value that falls in that day that can take advantage of indexes

Comment: As for the error, SQL Server designers in the 1990s made the unfortunate decision to use `timestamp` for [rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) values used in optimistic concurrency. That was fixed in 2008 but the old type name hasn't been removed yet. `rowversion` values shouldn't be used for anything other than concurrency checks of specific rows. They don't refer to a point in time

Comment: If you have to store the `unix_timestamp` as-is and are unwilling or unable to use `DATETIME2`, the correct type is `BIGINT` -- a 64-bit integer. Note that while an application can make sense of this, working with this on the database end is clumsy, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

[According to MSDN docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> The timestamp syntax is deprecated. This feature is in maintenance
>   mode and may be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server.
>   Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify
>   applications that currently use this feature.

Use data type `binary(8)` or `varbinary(8)` if you want `nullable` timestamp:

```
create table C (
user_id integer,
unix_timestamp binary(8),
platform varchar(50),
Action varchar(50)   
);
```

[As MSDN document says:](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> Timestamp is the synonym for the rowversion data type and is subject
>   to the behavior of data type synonyms. In DDL statements, use
>   rowversion instead of timestamp wherever possible. A nonnullable
>   rowversion column is semantically equivalent to a binary(8) column. A
>   nullable rowversion column is semantically equivalent to a
>   varbinary(8) column.

**UPDATE:**

AS MSDN says **you cannot convert a SQL Server TIMESTAMP to a date/time - it's just not a `date/time`**:

> Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary
>   numbers within a database. rowversion is generally used as a mechanism
>   for version-stamping table rows. The rowversion data type is just an
>   incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time. To record
>   a date or time, use a datetime2 data type.

But you can give a try. The Full example:

```
CREATE table C (
user_id integer,
unix_timestamp binary(8),
platform varchar(50),
Action varchar(50)   
)
```

Then insert data. I've got [Unix Timestamp here](https://www.unixtimestamp.com):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.C
(
    user_id,
    unix_timestamp,
    platform,
    Action
)
VALUES
(   1,    -- user_id - int
    1501688421, -- unix_timestamp - binary(8)
    'Android',   -- platform - varchar(50)
    'A'    -- Action - varchar(50)
    )

SELECT 
c.unix_timestamp
, DATEADD(S, c.unix_timestamp, '1970-01-01')
FROM dbo.C c
```

OUTPUT:

```
 2017-08-02 15:40:21.000
```

Or just create a table with correct DataType:

```
create table C (
user_id integer,
unix_timestamp DateTime2,
platform varchar(50),
Action varchar(50)   
);
```

Comment: when i tried to do as suggested unix_timestamp binary(8) and insert: INSERT INTO C 
VALUES ('102', 1501688421118, 'Android','A'); I got under unix_timestamp = 0x0D000001FEDA9AA3. from this value i can get GMT time. for example  the date should be Wednesday, August 2, 2017 3:40:21.118 PM.

Comment: I am getting error: Argument data type varbinary is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function. when running: SELECT 
c.unix_timestamp
, DATEADD(S, c.unix_timestamp, '1970-01-01')
FROM dbo.C c

Comment: @meital please, see my updated answer. I've double checked my code and it works. Unix TimeStamp has been got from here: https://www.unixtimestamp.com